# How to get authorization from request headers in custom TypeGraphQL AuthChecker

Tags: typescript, http-headers, authorization, apollo-server, typegraphql

I'm making a custom AuthChecker for a school project using TypeORM/GraphQL/ApolloServer, and I'm given a template for an AuthChecker looking like this:

```js
export const authChecker: AuthChecker<Context> = async (
    { root, args, context, info },
    roles
) => {
    const authorization = context.req.headers.authorization

    if(!authorization) return false

    try {
        const token = authorization.split(' ')[1]
        const payload = verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET!) as AccessTokenPayload
        context.payload = payload
    } catch (err) {
        log.info(err.message)
        return false
    }

  const user = await User.findOne(context.payload.userId)
  if (!user) return false

    return true
}
```

With this I get the error `Property 'authorization' does not exist on type 'Headers'.ts(2339)`

I also tried `context.req.headers.get("header name")` with different header names like `"Authorization"` and `"authorization"`, and while this compiles, it gives an error as response when running a query with the Apollo Explorer interface on an `@Authorized` field:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "name": "GraphQLError",
      "message": "context.req.headers.get is not a function"
...
```

I suspect the error must be with my Context, which is defined like this:

```js
export interface Context {
    req: Request
    res: Response
    payload: AccessTokenPayload
}

export interface AccessTokenPayload {
    userId: number
}
```

But I don't really have a clue what's wrong here, and literal hours of searching haven't really helped me out. My index file looks like this:

```js
( async () => {
    await createConnection()

    const server = new ApolloServer({
            schema: await buildSchema({
                resolvers: [
                    __dirname + '/**/*Resolver.{ts,js}',
                ],
                authChecker: authChecker,
                globalMiddlewares: [
                    ErrorInterceptor
                ]
            }),
            context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
    })
        console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`)
    })
})()
```

I also tried printing `context.req.headers`, which gives:

```json
{
  host: 'localhost:4000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '104',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"',       
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  accept: '*/*',
  origin: 'https://studio.apollographql.com',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,nb-NO;q=0.8,nb;q=0.7'
}
```

I don't know much about http requests/responses/headers so not sure what to make of that, doesn't really look like the right sort tho?!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was a simple import error, the Context interface was using default Fetch API Request/Response interfaces, instead of the Express Request/Response interfaces.